# Write a function that takes a string that replaces all occurrence of a number character [0...9] to be 1337 ​

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

Write a function that takes a string that replaces all occurrence of a number character [0...9] to be 1337 ​
This is what I have so far:

```
  var originalString= "You are 26 and I am 3 and she is 5";
  (originalString).replace(3, '1337');
```

Comment: Hehh so you want to replace `26` with `13371337`? (That's what I managed to understand! Yey)

Comment: Try using regexp with string.replace. `\d*` should match all numbers the way you want.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'd like to replace any number between 0 and 9 in a string with the string '1337'. So originalString should equal "You are 26 and I am 1337 and she is 1337".

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: @Vohuman I need to write a function that takes a string that replaces all occurrence of a number character [0…9] to be 1337 ​

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes the 1337 so special? What is the point of doing this?

Comment: @GabeB just added an answer to your question.  Hopefully I understood what you would like correctly.  If not, post a comment on my answer and I'll try to help.  If so, please mark it as a correct answer so that everyone else knows it's been solved :)  Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> I need to write a function that replaces numbers 0-9 in a string with '1337'

(as strange as it seems) here you go

```js
var originalString = "You are 26 and I am 3 and she is 5";
var modifiedString = originalString.replace(/\d/g, '1337');

console.log( modifiedString );
```

will replace every single number with 1337.

If you want **multiple digit numbers** to be replaced (NN===1337) than do like

```js
var originalString = "You are 26 and I am 3 and she is 5";
var modifiedString = originalString.replace(/\d+/g, '1337');

console.log( modifiedString );
```

... and here's your **function**

```js
function replaceNumWith1337( string ) {
  return string.replace(/\d/g, '1337');    // or use /\d+/g RegExp 
}


console.log( replaceNumWith1337("You are 26 and I am 3 and she is 5") );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to only replace numbers between 0-9 (as I have understood from your question) then this string of Regex should work :

```
/\b[0-9]\b/g
```

So your code would become this :

```js
var originalString = "You are 26 and I am 3 and she is 5";
var modifiedString = originalString.replace(/\b[0-9]\b/g, '1337');
    
console.log( modifiedString );
```

In case your are unfamiliar with Regex then here's a quick breakdown of why this would work.

The `\b` means word boundary, A.K.A the start or beginning of a word.  And `[0-9]` just means any character within the range of ASCII characters from 0-9.

Cheers,

Comment: @Oriol yep, misread the question...  my answer has been fixed now.  Not sure the downvote was necessary though :(